# Anchor Tag opens a new tab instead of downloading the file in Blazor Server Application

Tags: html, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server App and want to download a XML document. In my page there is a simple request for downloaing using an Anchor tag :

```html
<div>
    <a href="https://.../ASP/Calls/Call/CallGetForm.asp?adressindex=145&formid=Telefoneintrag" download="Telefonat_test.SPWFForm">
        <img src="/css/images/download.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

But it opens a new Tab instead of downloaing the file.

Is it possible to do it in Blazor server app? and what is my missing ?
This link works fine in our last versin of app in VB, but I think there is a issue with Blazor.

Have someone idea about it?

Comment: Browsers tend to be quite picky about downloads, so make sure it is not cross-site and don't change the name using the download attribute - Some browsers see that as a reason not to auto-download. So, the answer to your question is - yes it is possible to do this in a Blazor server app - you just need to make the browser happy and make sure the API sets the correct headers in the response - "application/octet-stream" is a good content type for downloads.

Comment: What is anything in the new tab?

Comment: Thank you Mister Magoo for your answer. The response header is "text/html; charset=Windows-1252" . Can it be the reason of the browser behaviour?

Comment: The response body is also a XML document, that actually I have to dowload it